# How to get the alpha value of a pixel in libpng?

Tags: c++, libpng

How can I get the alpha value of a pixel with the libpng.
The pixels values are stored int a `std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>`.
The RGB values are correctly decoded but the alpha value is sometimes 255 !
I thought that the alpha value should be between 0 and 1.
Thanks !

Comment: Both RGB and alpha values are generally 8-bit values, meanning integers in 0-255, where 255 is 1.0 or 100%.

Comment: No, between 0 and 255 for an 8-bit alpha channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment from Benny K solved my issue :
Both RGB and alpha values are generally 8-bit values, meanning integers in 0-255, where 255 is 1.0 or 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Several steps involved: Therefore, test by means of "png_get_IHDR" whether it is such image. Then read four times the width of each line and you will have the alpha value in the fourth pixel.